# which node points to usr/bin/node, cd usr/bin/node doesn't exist

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, ubuntu

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate: I've read several similar questions but haven't found a solution that explains this. Since I'm quite new to Linux (Elementary OS running on Ubuntu 12.04) I wanted to have a specific answer so I won't accidentally do something really stupid.

The last update on Node.js broke npm, and I don't know how to fix it. The easiest way for quick fixing seems to be just installing and reinstalling, so I learned how to do that. I'm using Chris Lea's ppa for Node.js.

Ran into some problems though. When running
`$ which node` I get the folder reference /usr/bin/node, so I then ran `$ cd /usr/bin/node`, and got the output: 
`bash: cd: /usr/bin/node: No such file or directory`. So I have a reference to a non-existing folder, and I have no idea to uninstall before reinstalling.

I'm able to run `node file.js` but neither `npm install package` or `sudo npm install package`. When running with sudo (I know that this is stupid - but I had to try 'cus I was so frustrated) nothing gets installed on the system, it just lists the files from the package.

I pasted a bash script a while ago, which created and put my globals in my user folder, in a folder named `.npm-packages`. I'm so new to Linux though, I have no idea how to fix this. The shebangs from the bin folder in `.npm-packages` works globally.

So lost - if you can help me I'm more than thankful.

Thanks alot,
Anton

Answer (score 5):

`node` is an executable file, not a directory. You can't `cd` to it.

You could `cd` to `/usr/bin/` which is the directory containing the `node` executable file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "Change Directory" into a file..

Inspect the path with `ls -l /path/to/something` and you'll probably see its a file or symlink. If its a directory it will list the contents.

To list info on a directory try adding the `d` flag.. EG: `ls -ld /directory/path`

Hang in there, this is the hardest part of the learning curve :-)

Comment: Thanks for responding - I've listed /usr/bin/ and got:
```lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          22 Mar 15 23:17 node -> /etc/alternatives/node``` for node and 
```lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          38 Jun 19 20:52 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js``` for npm.


Where do I go from here?

I'm finding the Linux learning curve to be quite steep, so all your help is appreciated. Sorry for taking so long to respond.

Answer (score -2):

This is what I did to get it working:

Step 1: Move ~/.npm to ~/.npm.bak

```
mv ~/.npm ~/.npm.bak
```

Step 2: Install a global npm package again, to recreate .npm
I installed Yeoman - which will help me help you!

```
npm install -g yo
```

Step 3: Follow what Yeoman tells you and paste the echo command it gives you

```
[Yeoman Doctor] Uh oh, I found potential errors on your machine

// lots of text here
...

Or run this command
echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/user/npm/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```